# error: unable to read input file as a property list: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I'm integrating Firebase to my Flutter app and setting up for iOS. I keep getting this error when I run the application.

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: unable to read input file as a property list: The operation couldn’t be
    completed. (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.) (in target 'Runner' from
    project 'Runner')
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have been facing the same problem with a newly imported Flutter project.
After some debugging, it seems like the issue was caused by a corrupt `GoogleService-Info.plist` file! Dunno why and how it was corrupted, because I have newly imported and existing project.

To solve this problem, you can follow those steps;

- Open your project in XCode
- delete the existing `GoogleService-Info.plist` file
- download the original one from Firebase
- then reimport/re-copy this file into your project

When this is done,
run `flutter clean` then try running it in iOS Simulator

This worked for me, hope it solves your problem too.

Comment: This worked for me: delete file, and again create GoogleService-Info.plist from xcode

Answer (score 11):

This indicates a problem with a `*.plist` file.

Doesn't matter if it is `GoogleService-Info.plist` one. It could be `Info.plist` or `Info-Debug.plist` or `Info-Release.plist` - literally any `.plist` file in your iOS project dir.

I suggest opening the `Xcode`, clicking every `.plist` file and checking it if opens fine. If not, the IDE would show you error - probably malformed `.plist` file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a one extra line `<true>` just after an `<array>`.

It's super easy to figure out the problem by running this helpful command to lint the .plist file.

`/usr/bin/plutil -lint LOCATION/TO/YOUR/info.plist`

It will identify the problem like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure you added all the permissions access that your app needed

in my case, it was solved by adding this. I hope it will you too:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to the location for distance calculation</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to the location for distance calculation</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to camera for profile picture</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to photo library for profile picture</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem is that ;

i commented like this,
//google

//facebook

the thing is that dont comment like this do
" <!- -    google - -> "

" <!- -    facebook- -> "

inshort press select line or word we want to delete then press command+/

this solved my problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to an error in the info.plist file.

In my case, the issue happened when I modified the file `<String>some message</String>` which is wrong and should be `<string>some message</string>` **in lowercase letters**.